# PhoneGap ipa file install issue

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am a **web developer**, my first time using phonegap to build an iOS app.

I have uploaded the required `.p12` certificates and provisioning profile but the `.ipa` refuses to install on any iOS device except for my iPhone (jailbroken).

The certificate and profile are production and distribution level so they are not for specific UDID's. 
The only issue I could think of could be related to the app id but I do not know where to specify the app id in phonegap.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Below is screenshot where id is specified which is suppose to be unique

[image]

But if you app is in production then it would have unique id.

Comment: I have been using build.phonegap.com to build  since i do not own a mac. All i did was upload my html files.

Comment: ohh but then you have some config xml right where u would hv specified ur App Id

Comment: it was not specified to do so but i will look into this

Comment: can u post ur project structure

Comment: just a bunch of html files css and js.

Answer (score 0):

Production and distribution? These are for .ipa files that you are uploading to the App Store, not for testing.

Use a Development profile and to make sure it works try it with and without specifying UDID.

Comment: It works as i mentioned on my iphone. It wont install on other ios devices.

Comment: its an internal app but i don't have access to the specific UDID's they are gonna be deployed in hence production and distribution.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. If you want to test it you should use a Development profile, that way you should be able to test it on other devices. If you're trying to install it on other devices why do you not have the UDIDs anyway? It works on yours presumably because you set up the profile with your own UDID.